# How to I override the java.util.PriorityQueue contains function?

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I have a PriorityQueue that contains objects of type box, which is my own class. How can I override the contains function to return true by looking at only one attribute of an object box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want something like this:

```
public class BoxPriorityQueue extends PriorityQueue<Box> {
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Box)) {
            return false;
        }
        Box box = (Box) obj;
        return box.getAttribute();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately generics doesn't apply to the `contains()` method so you have to cast it. This `BoxPriorityQueue` will otherwise only take `Box` objects since it extends `PriorityQueue<Box>`.

Comment: you should guard against ClassCastException by using an instanceof check on obj first: if(!(obj instanceof Box)) return false; ... rest of method ...

Comment: @LES2: True, I've added an `instanceof` check to the answer.

Comment: it's probably going to eff up the PriorityQueue, though, since it may rely on both the hashCode and equals method of the Box instances it contains for other things. Can't you supply a Comparator to the PriorityQueue (or either implement Comparable) and then do the custom logic in there? Doesn't seem right to subclass for such a trivial thing. :)

Comment: I agree with @LES2, you shouldn't be overriding contains... Use a comparator.